# How do I detect when I play a hyperlink in a UIWebView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, hyperlink, uiwebview

I have a problem:

How do I detect when I play a hyperlink in a UIWebView?

```
@synthesize webView = webView;

 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

webView.delegate = self;
webView=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

NSString* htmlContentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"<!DOCTYPE html>\
                               <html>\
                               <head>\
                               <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\
                               <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0\" />\
                               <title>Titulo</title>\
                               </head>\
                               <body style=\"margin:0;padding:0;font-family:'Helvetica'\">\
                               </body>\
                               </html>"];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlContentString baseURL:baseURL];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

}

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
    NSLog(@"ok!");
    return false;
}
return true;
```

}

I view with variables and print them as html, but I shouldStartLoadWithRequest function does not detect anything.

I'm using delegate uiwevbiew.

Should I do it with javascript?

Greetings.

Comment: You are setting the delegate of web view before initialising the web view object..  Add delegate line below the WebView allocation line..

Comment: Please upvote at least buddy.. :) beside my comment..